# Buick Rendezvous 3400 SFI no start when warm/hot

Tags: starting, buick, valve, rendezvous

The problem is that when the engine is warm/hot it does not want to start. I can crank it all day long but it doesn't even sputter. Things I checked:

-Fuel pressure

-Spark (It seems weak? Has an orange tinge to it.)

-Compression (Both when the engine is warm and cold.)

-Camshaft and Crankshaft position sensor (Replaced the Camshaft Position sensor even though the old one turned to be fine.)

When the engine runs it runs perfectly fine, no wierd noises, no missfires, no stuttering.

**Also, this all happened after replacing a bent valve.**

**UPDATE#1:**
I think I narrowed it down to a fuel issue. Today I checked and cleaned all the connections that go from the main wiring harness. After that, it fired right up (the engine was cold). After a short drive (15min) I shut the engine off and it didn't want to start after that. I found a can of carb cleaner and while a helper was cranking the engine I sprayed some in the intake...it was running, but as soon as I stoped spraying it would stall. Once again I checked if the fuel rail had pressure and it did. Can the injectors stop working when they are warm? I replaced all of them a month ago.

**UPDATE#2:**
I just gave the car to an actual mechanic. We talked for a bit and he said that it's either a bad ground (I may have forgotten to clean or attach a ground to the engine block, I doubt this though :) ) or the crankshaft sensor goes bad only when its hot, but some how it still runs when the engine reaches operating temperature(???). Time will tell.

**UPDATE#3:**
The car is fixed now. There were a couple reasons why the car didn't start. The crankshaft seal failed and was dripping oil on the pulley and crankshaft sensor attracting oil and debris causing a weak signal. The wiring harness probably got damaged while replacing the valve and had live wires exposed. All in all the sensor was good.

**A big thank you for all the suggestions and help!**

Comment: Which valve? Exhaust or inlet? Or pcv?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @SolarMike The engine had a bent intake valve on cylinder #3.

Comment: Are you getting injector pulse?

Comment: @Ben That's the thing that i'm not sure about. I only checked if the injector fuse is getting power and it is. I can't really get to the 2 pin connectors that are on each injector and stick a noid light or led without dismantling the upper intake manifold. If this is the case what could cause no injector pulse when the engine is warm?

Comment: Poor harness connections possibly there should be a subharness connector that gives you access to all the injector wires iirc.

Answer (score 1):

The crankshaft seal failed and was dripping oil on the pulley and crankshaft sensor attracting oil and debris causing a weak signal. The wiring harness probably got damaged while replacing the valve and had live wires exposed.